# elastic net- confidence intervals for parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, elastic-net

Can I see the intervals and p values for each coefficient in elastic net model?
I wrote:

```
elastNet<-cv.glmnet(pred, comp,alpha=.8,standardize = TRUE, family="binomial",type.measure="auc")
```

If I write the following I get the numbers, but no intervals.

```
coef(elastNet)
```

Also I can add the parameter s (I guess is the lambda value)

```
coef(elastNet,s=0.01)
```

To choose a lambda value first I saw the graph:

[image]

And also considered:

```
> elastNet$lambda.min
[1] 0.0007603077
> elastNet$lambda.1se
[1] 0.01492515
```

So I decided to choose sth in the middle:

```
coef(elastNet,s=0.01)
```

And I got 26 variables with values (I had 59).

I would like to know the confidence interval for each variable. Can I get some idea of this form the following graph?

[image]

Also, I f I need the KS measure, does the software provides it?

Comment: why do you want the confidence intervals?  The parameter estimates are all biased and therefore any inference will be misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible; see [these slides](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/covtest-talk.pdf) [PDF] of Rob Tibshirani. Slide 13 mentions they can't *yet* provide a p-value for terms in a lasso model. Those slides describe a test that gives p-values of terms as they enter the Lasso model.

One further assumes therefore that confidence intervals are not available either.

Comment: If you are interested in this test, there is a [paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/covtest.pdf) and an [R package](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/covTest_1.0.tar.gz) too. These links and some discussion are from [Andrew Gelman's blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2013/03/18/tibshirani-announces-new-research-result-a-significance-test-for-the-lasso/)

Answer (score 0):

There is the selectiveInference package in R, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/index.html, that provides confidence intervals and p values for your coefficients fitted by the LASSO, based on the following paper:

[Stephen Reid, Jerome Friedman, and Rob Tibshirani (2014). A study of error variance estimation in lasso regression. arXiv:1311.5274](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5274)

I think the approach would require some modifications for the elastic net though...